# Как сделать проверку на наличие хотя бы одной буквы?

Tags: javascript

Пишу чат, делаю в нем возможность отправки по нажатию на Enter и в моем коде идет проверка на наличие хотя бы одного символа в строке, но когда нажимаешь несколько раз на Enter, то происходит отправка сообщения.

Как мне решить данную ситуацию?

```
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            submitCahtMessage();
        }

        return false;
    }


    function submitCahtMessage(from = false){

        if(!!chat_message.value && chat_message.value.length > 1) {
            console.log('сообщение: '+chat_message.value+'');


                templateMessage('client','',''+chat_message.value+'');

                sendFunction('/chat/');

                chat_message.value = '';

            autoScroll()
        } else{
            console.log('нужно ввести сообщение');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обрезайте все пробельные символы

```
if(!!chat_message.value && chat_message.value.trim().length > 1) {
```

Comment: спасибо большое